# tools.jar not on classpath anymore?

Tags: java, lombok

I recently reformatted my system from Fedora 15 32 to Fedora 15 64-bit. I installed the 64-bit version of Java, started up a fresh Netbeans instance, tried to build my project which uses Project Lombok, and got this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/parser/Scanner$Factory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at lombok.delombok.DelombokApp$1.loadStreamAsClass(DelombokApp.java:102)
    at lombok.delombok.DelombokApp$1.loadClass(DelombokApp.java:117)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at lombok.delombok.Delombok.delombok(Delombok.java:358)
    at lombok.delombok.Delombok.main(Delombok.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at lombok.delombok.DelombokApp.runApp(DelombokApp.java:55)
    at lombok.core.Main.go(Main.java:127)
    at lombok.core.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner$Factory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at lombok.delombok.DelombokApp$1.loadClass(DelombokApp.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more
```

I have never gotten this error before. This particular error came from the Maven exec plugin trying to execute lombok to delombok some source code. On the old system this worked all the time without problems. Now its not.

What's puzzling is that on the old system it worked even though I used both Java 6 and later Java 7 without having to do anything special. I also frequently deleted Netbeans and its files, either upgrading to a new version or just wanting to speed it up again. So there isn't any special settings or checkboxes I might of changed in either program. Even then, I don't remember doing anything special to get it working.

Why am I all of a sudden getting this error? Why is tools.jar not automatically being added to the classpath? And if that's normal behavior, then how did it work before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I finally figured out what the issue was: Java 6 was installed originally and I jumped straight to Java 7.

Essentially I was running Netbeans and Maven on Java 7 which was in a folder in my home folder. I had Java 6 actually installed in the OS and it was on my path. Apparently Java 6 (at least the Linux versions) includes tools.jar by default, which allows Lombok to execute correctly. Java 7 does not.

When the Maven Exec Plugin ran, it actually used Java 6 even though I had started Maven under Java 7. When Java 6 was replaced with 7, it no longer worked, causing this error.

Comment: Java is goind more modular now. In some extent, that's a feature related to your issue : http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/java-get-more-modular-jdk-7-upgrade-919

Comment: May I say my answer was not so fat away @TheLQ ?

Answer (score 0):

does java link to the right version ?

```
java -version 

type java
```

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Yes its the right version. Netbeans uses java in `/usr/java/default/` which is symlinked to jdk1.7.0. The java bianary is also symlinked to the correct version. Everything is correct

Comment: Are you sure it is linked to jdk not jre ?

Comment: Yes, javac is in `/usr/java/default/bin/javac`. The JRE is inside a folder

Comment: and can you build a tiny test project without lombok ?

Comment: Yes, a basic project compiles just fine.

Comment: Sorry, it seems the issue was elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000578/tools-jar-not-on-classpath-anymore/7025824#7025824